# GLIBC Configuration Error on Solaris

Tags: solaris, glibc

Recently I had to work with glibc to be installed on Solaris OS on the x86 platform.
The problem I encountered with was the configuration of the glibc package. I was getting multiple errors.Some of them have been higlighted under:

```
      configure:3641: g++ -c -g -O2  conftest.cc >&5
      conftest.cc:10:31: error: 'void std::exit(int)' should have been declared inside    
                                'std'
      configure:3647: $? = 1
```

To be noted I am using glibc-2.3.5.
I could only find out that the glibc ports have not been developed for Solaris platform.

Comment: That's a C++ error. If you don't need C++ support, maybe there's a `configure` option to skip it.

Comment: Why do you need glibc instead of Solaris libc?   GNU libc is mainly for Linux these days, since other OS'es provide their own libc already.

Comment: the issue is there is some middle-ware already installed on Linux. Next I need it to be installed on Solaris. For linux, the Glibc package was needed for its installation but I don't know if in solaris the Solaris libc can work in place of glibc. Now the configuration here tries to run a test program(conftest.c) to check for the present gnu libc version and fails in there.

Comment: [opencsw](http://www.opencsw.org/) has binaries and does have glibc.

Comment: I don't see glibc on opencsw. Can you post a link?