# ld.so.1: protoc: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found in Solaris 11

Tags: c++, linux, protobuf-c

I Installed protobuffer in my solaris 11, Now to generate the addressbook.pb.h and addressbook.pb.cc file i gave given below command

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

but instead of getting desired file i got given below error:

```
ld.so.1: protoc: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by file /export/home/shivamv/Downloads/PROTO_BUFF/protobuf-master/src/.libs/libprotobuf.so.15)
 ld.so.1: protoc: fatal: libstdc++.so.6: open failed: No such file or directory
```

I checked libstdc++.so.6 by given below command:

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

so i got this output:

```
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGT
```

Please help me to resolve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's pretty straight forward.

> fatal: libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

All that message is telling you is that you need **GLIBCXX**, specifically version 3.4.20 (it might support a *later* version instead), but that it isn't installed.

`libstdc++` is just the standard C++ library, and it does *not* include the actual GLIBCXX library. It only knows you need that library - or specifically that `libprotobuf` does  - and it isn't finding it.

---

Now, I work on Linux, and personally don't know how to install anything on Solaris specifically. It *appears* that GLIBCXX is part of GLIBC, [which apparently needs to be built from source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18810300/472647). However, like I said, I don't know Solaris specifically, so I could be wrong on that part.

Comment: CodeMouse92 : Not glibc, but the (gnu)lib(std)cxx → libstdc++. `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` is an object in the gcc libstdc++, from version 4.9.0 ( libstdc++.so.6.0.20 )  Please try `$ objdump -x /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.20`

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution, however you can tell the runtime linker to ignore the shared library versions.

```
export LD_NOVERSION=1
```

but it is working for me.